# How to train TensorFlow on large images? (4288x2848)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, memory-management, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets

I want to train my TensorFlow model on large images (4288x2848 pixels), but it just loads all images in my vRAM and i dont have enough vRAM for this (on my GPU is only 8GB - I use TensorFlow for GPU, so it doesn´t use normal RAM). Is there any way how to use these high res images? Like loading them gradually and gradually delete them from vRAM after epoch is done?

Already tried smth like memory_growth to my GPU

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
   tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

and mixed float 16

```
mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')
```

It worked, that I was able to put resolution up to 750*1500 (or smt like this, I am not sure)

Answer (score 0):

use the keras ImageDataGenerator. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) The generator breaks up the data into batches. The user sets the batch size(number of images in a batch) Batches are run sequentially. The memory used for the data is proportional to the batch size. For example assume you have 500 images. For the generator if you set the batch size to 25 then for an epoch 20 sequential batches of data are presented for training. Memory used is proportinal to the size of 25 images versus the full size of the dataset of 500 images